# Prove that $2^{15}-1$ is divided by $11\cdot31\cdot61$?

Tags: congruences

I have to prove that $2^{15}-1$ is divided by $11\cdot31\cdot61$. 
I have proven using congruencies that $2^{15}-1$ is divided by $31$. However we have

$$2^5\equiv 10 \mod{11}$$
$$2^{15}\equiv 10^3=1000\equiv 10 \pmod {11}$$
Therefore
$$2^{15}-1\equiv 9 \pmod{11}.$$
So it is impossible to prove!!

Comment: Yes, it is true. What's the question?

Comment: By the way, the smallest number of the form $2^n-1$ which is divisible by $11,31,61$ is $2^{60}-1$.

Comment: The given number is not divisible by 11, or am I missing something?

Comment: $2^{15}\equiv \left(\frac{2}{31}\right)\equiv 1\pmod{\! 31}$ using [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_criterion) and [Quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: @user26486: I was just in time to correct. Thanks you!

Comment: Shorter: $2^5\equiv −1\mod11$, hence $2^{15}\equiv (−1)^3\equiv−1\mod11$.

Comment: How do you prove using congruencies that $2^{60}-1$ is divided by 61?

Comment: I did it, still my opinion is it's more accurate to write `=` when there is no reduction .

Comment: @parkhyeyoo [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem): $\gcd(a,p)=1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\! p}$.

Comment: I am not allowed to use Fermat's theorem. Only congruencies.

Comment: $2^6\equiv -3\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{60}\equiv (-3)^{10}\equiv 3^{10}\equiv \left(3^{5}\right)^2 \equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{\! 61}$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, there is a mistake in the problem. Here are two useful prime factorizations:
$$
\begin{align*}
2^{15}-1&=32767=7\cdot 31\cdot 151\\
2^{15}+1&=32769=3^2\cdot 11\cdot 331
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the factorization you are given is wrong.

Since $N=2^{15}-1=(2^5)^3-1=(2^5-1)((2^5)^2+2^5+1)$ you get
$$
2^{15}-1=31\cdot(1024+32+1)=31\cdot 1057
$$
However, you can also use
$$
2^{15}-1=(2^3)^5-1=(2^3-1)((2^3)^4+(2^3)^2+2^3+1)
$$
so $N$ is also divisible by $7$. Divide $1057$ by $7$ to get
$$
N=31\cdot 7\cdot 151
$$
(and $151$ is prime).